# RepeatColumns="2" overlaps CheckBoxList checkbox on second column

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

Here is my asp.net code

```
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">                        
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkCourseList" runat="server" style="margin-left:10px;" class="checkbox-inline" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatColumns="2" textalign="left">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>                            
            </asp:Panel>
```

this is the issue:

Course name Check box getting selected when clicked next to course name

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2tiO.png)

I want the checkbox on the right of the text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove `RepeatColumns` or set `RepeatColumns = "1"`as you text line is broad. or you can use *padding* in your style

Comment: I'm not sure it's a CheckBoxList issue, it's should be a css issue so we can not help you without some other information about style... =(

Answer (score 0):

This is only `css` issue which can be solved by using `TextAlign="left"`.

```
  <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">                        
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkCourseList" runat="server" style="margin:10px;" class="checkbox-inline" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatColumns="2" TextAlign="left">
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>                            
                </asp:Panel>
```

If Line is too broad. You can add some **padding** in your *style* or you could use `RepeatColumns = "1"`.

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Each listItem in a `<asp:CheckBoxList..>` are rendered as a combination of `type="checkbox"` and `label`. so you can apply style to the `label` Like the following:

```
.checkbox-inline label{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    max-width: 112px; /* use width based on requirement */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

So if the